# how do I change the thickness of a doughnut chart in SSRS?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, charts

I basically want to make the hole of the doughnut bigger so that the chart itself is thinner.

The green needs to be thinner:

[image]

Comment: I've been duped, i though someone was giving away thick doughnuts in here :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's *the* answer but [there's one answer at msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d05db2af-8b3c-4b8c-81b6-0f04c3acfa50/some-questions-related-to-donut-charts-in-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices):

> ***Question***
>
> *Some questions related to donut charts in SSRS*
>
> - *How to customize the thickness of donut in donut chart and radius of inside and outside circle (the other thickness).*
>
> ***Reply***
>
> *Instead of Using a Dounut Charts, you can use Gauge Chart.*
>
> *Firstly select the inner area of the gauge and from the options remove the labels, minor & major tick marks. Secondly from gauge properties remove the Frame of the Gauge. Now U will be left over with only the "Range" part of the Gauge chart.You can add number of ranges to get the 360 Dounut look. You can specify each "Range" start & end range with hard code values or expression . Playing with the Range general properties, you can achieve the mentioned customization. You can add a Label to the Gauge and place it in the center*

Comment: thank you Gerold. Will give this a try. By the way, funny you're from Austria. I'll be visiting soon :)

Comment: @Rj. Apparently something whispered to me to give you a quick answer here to give you a warm welcome in advance :) Enjoy your stay!

Answer (score 6):

Click on the Doughnut and look at the Chart Series properties.  Under General > Custom Attributes, change the DoughnutRadius property.